# Creating a new record from a visualforce page of a different object type

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm looking to create a custom button on the Case object that launches a visualforce page. I want the visualforce page to be a different standard controller type.  From what I can tell I can't do this. How would you go about doing this? Code examples would help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either go with a JavaScript button that takes you to a Visualforce page or you'll need to have a Visualforce page that extends Case which immediately redirects you to a non-case Visualforce page. Since that's ugly and unnecessary, just make a JavaScript button on your Case object (name|setup|app setup|customize|cases|buttons and links|new then select OnClick JavaScript for Content Source).

Then in JavaScript:

```
parent.location.href ='/apex/YourNonCaseVisualforcePage';
```

EDIT: Check out [this tutorial](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Tutorial%3a_Modal_Dialogs_in_Visualforce_using_the_Yahoo!_User_Interface_Library) for tips on sending data back from a popup to Visualforce.

Comment: Great thanks. I ended up doing this. I have it direct to a visualforce page to capture the data. I'm struggling with getting the popup to close on either close or cancel and update fields on the case record the vf page was launched from. Will onclick =" window.close() return true/ false ". Work for returning so bool to help drive my logic statement? The onclick would be on the vf  page as an attribute to the save and cancel cmd.